# Number of ways to travel for an ant

Tags: combinatorics

An ant is at the point $(5,5)$ of a grid. It wishes to reach $(21,23)$. The only moves allowed for it are one unit right or one unit left. But it can never land on a point where both coordinates are composite numbers. In how many ways can it reach it's destination?

By bruteforcing with small cases,i saw the answer comes to be the regular number of ways in a grid problem which is $34C16$ in this case. But i am still struggling how to prove it.

Comment: I assume you mean right and up rather than left and up. The result you give is the one for the problem without the restriction on composite coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Note that to reach $(21, 23)$ such that at least one of the coordinates is prime, you need to reach it via $(19, 23)$, as the points $(20, 22)$, $(21, 21)$, $(21, 22)$ have all coordinates composite. So, in fact, you're looking for a number of paths from $(5, 5)$ to $(19, 23)$. Now, the primes from $5$ to $23$ are:
$$5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23.$$
As you can only travel via nodes with at least one prime coordinate, your usable grid is smaller than the full grid. For example, you can only reach $(7, 7)$ from $(5, 5)$ in two ways instead of six, because you cannot go via $(6, 6)$. So, your actual grid dimensions are $6 \times 7$: there are $6$ primes from $5$ to $19$ and $7$ primes from $5$ to $23$. This simply reduces to the number of ways you can reach the point $(5, 6)$ from the point $(0, 0)$ on a standard grid without the "at-least-one-prime-coordinate" requirement. This gives you the answer:
$$\binom{(5-0)+(6-0)}{5}=\binom{11}{5}=462$$